# Are the automatic captions of the videos being created using the Google Cloud Speech technology?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

If I use the audio of one good YouTube video as input for the Google Could Speech API, would you say that I will get the "same" transcript as the one automatically provided by YouTube?

Comment: Even if it's not exactly the same, it would theoretically be very close...

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested on how Youtube automatic captions work, read their blog [Automatic captions in YouTube](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/automatic-captions-in-youtube.html):

> To help address this challenge, we've combined Google's automatic
>   speech recognition (ASR) technology with the YouTube caption system to
>   offer automatic captions, or auto-caps for short. Auto-caps use the
>   same voice recognition algorithms in Google Voice to automatically
>   generate captions for video. The captions will not always be perfect
>   (check out the video below for an amusing example), but even when
>   they're off, they can still be helpful—and the technology will
>   continue to improve with time.

Credits to this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-YouTube-subtitles-work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that blog post, but it is quite old. I am also inclined to think that both things use the same or at least very similar technologies/engines/implementations to do ASR.